# Retrieve unknown number of GET values and put in one database row

Tags: php, database, sqlite, post, get

I'm trying to make a small project for house automation. Basically my hardware call a php (v5.6) script hosted on my WIFI router (gl-ar150) in order to transmit and storage the data in a SQLite (v3) database.

Due to the evolution of needs, I do not know how many values will be sent in the future but not more than 50.

Basically I'm doing it in this way. Getting the variables with $_GET, and it seems pretty:
`$id = $_GET[ch];`
BUT, I'm preparing an SQL request, ugly part
`$db->prepare('UPDATE history SET div = div+1, val1=val1+?, val2=val2+?, val3=val3+?, val4=val4+?, val5=val5+? WHERE date='.$date[last_minute]);`
Then I'm binding it in a foreach loop, pretty enough
`$i++;
 $upd->bindValue($i,$val);`

I'm looking for a solution for the ugly part refactoring. Before I'm starting to do some awful string manipulations. It's allowed to entry zero or null values into database, it's also allowed to modify the get method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you going to be getting your column names from the GET as well to forge the row of data to insert?

Comment: Hi @BJBlack, no not really needed, It will be only defined in Frontend. In database itself first is my ID (unix timestamp) the next fields are numeric values like val1, val2 .. val50...